# Why Android Studio imports the complete package on Reformatting the code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, hashmap

I have a class which uses HashMap and I have imported 
import java.util.HashMap.

On executing reformat code -> eclipse shortcut used Cntrl+Shift+R

It reformats and convert to import java.util.*

Why android studio imports all classes if we need only one , here HashMap? Isn't it unnecessary.

Comment: Please mention android studio version

Comment: Can you share screenshot where it has imported unnecessary packages? I Guess it will not import automatically. and if we have added unnecessary packages it will show grayed out text.

Comment: @MayurSojitra its 3.4.1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If any package is having more than **N numbers** of import of the **same package** in Android studio, it automatically converts it to **`*`** imports for that package *(default are **5** for Top-level Symbols and **3** for Java Statics and Enum Members)*.

So, for example if you're having some N number of imports from package **`java.util`**, it gets converted to **`java.util.*`**.

### Where to find that setting to change it?

1. Open Settings from **File-> Settings** in Android Studio *(ctrl+alt+s)*.
2. Go to **Editor -> Code Style -> Java/Kotlin** and open **imports tab** then change that **N number** to any of your suitable case.

[image]

There are other options available as well.

Answer (score 4):

From Intellij official [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html#disable-wildcard-imports)

> When the number of classes that IntelliJ IDEA has imported from the same package reaches the limit    (5 by default), the IDE modifies the statements in order to import the entire package instead   of importing several single classes from this package.

You can disable this feature like following.

> 1. In the **Settings/Preferences** dialog (`Ctrl+Alt+S`), select **Code Style | Java | Imports**.
> 2. Make sure that the **Use single class import** option is enabled.
> 3. In the **Class count to use import with** ‘*’ and **Names count to use static import with** ‘*’ fields, specify values that definitely exceed the number of classes in a package and the number of names in a class (for example, **999**).